# How to get IDs of rows, that are identical in some columns but have NAs in others

Tags: r

I have a data frame with some rows, that are the same in some columns, and should be identical, but are instead filled with `NA`.

Example:

```
     ID   NAME   SURNAME      value1     value2
1     1  Luke Skywalker            1         3 
2     2  Luke Skywalker            NA        NA
3     3  Luke Skywalker            NA        NA
4     6   Han      Solo            NA        NA
5     7   Han      Solo            5         5 
6     8   Han      Solo            4         NA
```

In reality, this is a big dataset and there are more than just two values.

I would like get a vector of `ID`of the rows, that have the same `Name`and `Surname`, but have have `NA` values in columns, where the column with the same name and surname has actual values. If there is a case, where there is mixed data (as is the case here with `Han`), I would like to just get the `ID` of the row, that has only `NA`data, except if there is a full row with values, that are the same as the ones in the incomplete row, then I would also like to get the `ID` of the incomplete one.

So the return from my example would be `c(2,3,6)`

**Edit:** As asked in the question, the names and surnames are important, as I would only like to get the `ID` if and only if there is a full or more complete row for that name surname combination. The variables are actually the results of test, that should happen only once per year (in my df, I will also group by the testing date, I skipped that here as the grouping variables should have no influence on the solution, as far as I know).

Comment: Aren't you simply looking for `which(is.na(df$value1) & is.na(df$value2))`? Could  you explain why the `Name Surname` matters?

Comment: @CPak I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

This would be an example to get "vector of IDof the rows, that have the same Nameand Surname, but have have NA values in columns" & "just get the ID of the row, that has only NAdata":

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = " ID   NAME   SURNAME      value1     value2
1     1  Luke Skywalker            1         3 
             2     2  Luke Skywalker            NA        NA
             3     3  Luke Skywalker            NA        NA
             4     6   Han      Solo            NA        NA
             5     7   Han      Solo            5         5 
             6     8   Han      Solo            4         NA ")

df[apply(df[ , c("value1", "value2")], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))), ]
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question, to make it clearer, that I need to have a more complete or better yet, full row, to get the ID of the one with NA, not only always get the NA rows ID.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `rowSums` on logical matrix created using the subset of dataset that have only 'value' columns.  It is vectorized and should work on any number of 'value' columns in the dataset

```
df[!rowSums(!is.na(df[grep("value", names(df))])),]
#  ID NAME   SURNAME value1 value2
#2  2 Luke Skywalker     NA     NA
#3  3 Luke Skywalker     NA     NA
#4  6  Han      Solo     NA     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter_at(vars(-ID, -NAME, -SURNAME), all_vars(is.na(.)))

  ID NAME   SURNAME value1 value2
1  2 Luke Skywalker     NA     NA
2  3 Luke Skywalker     NA     NA
3  6  Han      Solo     NA     NA
```

`filter_at` is a way to filter a condition for multiple columns. We can use `vars(...)` to select the columns we want. In the above example, `vars(-ID, -NAME, -SURNAME)` means the filtering condition is not applied to the `ID`, `NAME`, and `SURNAME` columns. Because you said you need to filter the condition for more than two columns, I want to demonstrate other ways to specify the columns for filtering. The following code, with other ways to specify columns, will also work.

```
# Select columns to begin with "value"
df %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("value")), all_vars(is.na(.)))

# Select columns to contain "value"
df %>% filter_at(vars(contains("value")), all_vars(is.na(.)))

# Select columns to match "value" using regular expression
df %>% filter_at(vars(matches("value")), all_vars(is.na(.)))

# Select columns by column index numbers, not using the first three columns
df %>% filter_at(vars(-1:-3), all_vars(is.na(.)))

# Select columns by column index numbers, starting the fourth column to the end
df %>% filter_at(vars(4:ncol(.)), all_vars(is.na(.)))
```

`all_vars(is.na(.))` means all the columns specified need to meet the filtering condition (`is.na(.) == TRUE`).

#### Data

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = " ID   NAME   SURNAME      value1     value2
1     1  Luke Skywalker            1         3 
                 2     2  Luke Skywalker            NA        NA
                 3     3  Luke Skywalker            NA        NA
                 4     6   Han      Solo            NA        NA
                 5     7   Han      Solo            5         5 
                 6     8   Han      Solo            4         NA ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly :)

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = " ID   NAME   SURNAME      value1     value2
1     1  Luke Skywalker            1         3 
             2     2  Luke Skywalker            NA        NA
             3     3  Luke Skywalker            NA        NA
             4     6   Han      Solo            NA        NA
             5     7   Han      Solo            5         5 
             6     8   Han      Solo            4         NA ")

all_or_some_na  <- which(unname(apply(df[4:ncol(df)],1,anyNA)))
all_na          <- which(unname(apply(df[4:ncol(df)],1,function(x) all(is.na(x)))))
some_na         <- setdiff(all_or_some_na,all_na)
complete_rows   <- setdiff(1:nrow(df),all_or_some_na)
```